# Ui_component column visible doesn't work

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.2.6

In Magento 2.2.6, modifying customer listing to add custom columns, setting  to set a default visibility is not being taken into account. It doest not matter if it is set to true or false. It does not make any change.

The  is working, since we are able to change column name. For example, see "Web Site 2" column name.

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">  
<columns name="customer_columns">
    <column name="mod_cardcode" class="Mod\CustomerCrm\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cardcode">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Company customer code</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">25</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>      
    <column name="group_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="50">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>         
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="100">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="website_id" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="110">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Web Site 2</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="confirmation" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Confirmation" sortOrder="130">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>        
</columns>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<column name="website_id" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="110">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Web Site 2</item>
            <item name="statefull" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Keep in mind that all applied changes stored inside bookmarks table, so check it with another custom column. If you want to hide general column (from the base Magento setup) you should make modifications in the `ui_bookmark` table directly. Data in that table stored for each listing and looks like this:

[image: ui_bookmark table data]

Comment: also ```<statefull><property name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</property</statefull>```